# Google maps ios 8 swift crashing unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, swift

l have followed all the steps on the google for ios sdk and imported all the libraries and headers, did set up my key on the appdelegate and my app including #import  on the bridging header, then went to my Project NOT Target as per instructions please see attachment, l can but still my app crashes  with `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`[image: Objc image][image: appdelegate][image: myclass]

Comment: You might want to clean your project, and restart your XCode. Also you can check out and compare my github Google Maps iOS SDK for Swift demo project: https://github.com/ziyang0621/GoogleMaps-Swift which I successfully added Google Maps framework to my Swift app. Also you might want to show the code of your bridging-header file.

Comment: Hi ztan i have tried it now l am getting this error http://stackoverflow.com/a/28421363/2040407

Comment: oh, forgot to mention, you need to add the required frameworks/libraries in the step 6 : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project

Comment: Yes bro i did add all of the libraries, l made a separate app to test and its working fine , but the main app is not keeps crashing