# Google maps for iOS crashing

Tags: xcode, google-maps, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hi l am having a problem implementing google maps for iOS I have put all the relevant frameworks and added the -ObjC under Project NOt target and I am getting this error:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCacheProperty' for entity 'GMSCacheProperty'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2015-02-09 22:48:01.326 AlertPoint[8038:957015] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GMSCachedObject' for entity 'GMSCachedObject'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
2015-02-09 22:48:01.730 AlertPoint[8038:957014] +[NSData gtm_dataByInflatingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x197f9d480
```

I have set the key and matched it to the bundle identifier as required and followed all the step, its been 3 days and No Luck. Please help.

That's how my iOS simulator looks:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You should add the @objc add to your NSManagedObject-class which you save in the CoreData:

```
@objc(GMSCacheProperty)
class GMSCacheProperty { 

}
```

Comment: thanks man where do i put this class i a using swift and my project does'nt have coreData besides the framework